# Getting Number from Element's Text and Injecting into an xpath string via ProtractorJS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**Background**

Essentially what I want to do is to grab text from an element on one page. Parse that grabbed text into a number but which remains in string format, so I can further use it for an xpath query string. See the code below

```
var bookingRefString = element(by.css(".panel-header span")).getText();
var bookingRef = String(bookingRefString).match(/\d+/);
element(by.id("menu_item_control")).click();
element(by.xpath(".//tr/td[1]//*[text()='" + bookingRef + "']/../..")).click();
```

**The error I get back**

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, .//tr/td[1]//*[text()='null']/../..)
```

**What I can conclude from this problem**

So to conclude it's quite clear that it's not parsing the bookingRefString for the number as stated from 'null' being injected into the xpath.

Comment: So step 1 would seem to be solving the null problem. You should print the `bookingRefString` and see if it's also null. If it's not, are you getting the expected text? Is your regex correct? and so on...

Comment: Yup the bookingRefString outputted to the console does return a valid string, which leads me to believe the parsing isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
element(by.css(".panel-header span")).getText().then((bookingRefString) => {
    var bookingRef = bookingRefString.match(/\d+/);
    element(by.id("menu_item_control")).click();
    element(by.xpath(".//tr/td[1]//*[text()='" + bookingRef + "']/../..")).click();    
});
```